# EXP reduction to show NEXP-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

I wonder why can't I allow an exponential-time reduction from all problems in $\textbf{NEXP}$ to a language $L$ and claim $L$ to be $\text{NEXP-complete}$.

The computational complexity class $\text{NEXPTIME}$  or $\text{NEXP}$ has been defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXPTIME). In the same page, there is a section on $\text{NEXP-complete}$. This section states that the reduction must *polynomial* time. For the case of the deterministic version of this class, we can not have exponential time reductions as having exponential time reduction leads to all problems in $\textbf{EXP}$ be $\textbf{EXP-complete}$.

This reasoning is also held for the class $\textbf{P}$, which is why we have log-space reductions defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete#:%7E:text=In%20computational%20complexity%20theory%2C%20a,it%20by%20an%20appropriate%20reduction.). But when we are talking about $\textbf{NP}$ we deal with polynomial-time reductions. By same logic, I should be allowed exponential-time reductions for $\textbf{NEXP}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete statement about completeness for complexity classes is "Problem A is complete for complexity class B under C-reductions."

In many cases it is clear from the context what notion of reducibility we are using, and so we can get away with not mentioning it explicitly. For P-completeness, it is clear that we mean logspace reductions if not stated otherwise, for NP-completeness we mean polytime reductions unless stated otherwise. The wiki page you link is clarifying that they are using polytime reductions for NEXP-completeness, too.

Of course you can go and study completeness for NEXP under EXP-reductions. But since "Problem A is complete for NEXP under EXP-reductions." is a much weaker statement than "Problem is complete for NEXP under polytime reductions.", it would be preferable to make the latter statement whenever you can prove it.